# Efficient quantum algorithm for CLASSICAL FFT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing

Is there a known improvement on the current O(n*log(n)) algorithm for CLASSICAL FFT using quantum computation? 'n' is the number of samples.

I need to find the amplitude and phase of the K dominating (highest amplitude) frequencies, where K is a fixed constant and K is much smallet then n.

Comment: Do you want the full result, or is it sufficient to sample from it?

Comment: Thank you Craig Gidney for the comment. I updated the question.

Comment: I do not know about quantum algorithms, but if you allow some approximation this can be done classically faster than $O(n\log n)$ http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ecprice/papers/hikp12.pdf.